# External HDD accidentally unlocked from launcher

Tags: hard-drive, launcher

In Ubuntu 14.04 I accidentally unlocked from launcher my external HDD.
How can I have it back there?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when you connect your external hard drive open dash and type the drives names(partitions names of your external harddrive) then drag that drive to launcher

Comment: Thank you! Great! It works! And it was an incredible fast answer.

Comment: @DumitruCristian you may want to mark the answer as correct with a green check mark on the left margin.